# SFTP in c# using a webclient

Tags: c#, ftp

I am working on a ftp code in c#. The thing is am using a webclient to do ftp. Now I would like to do SFTP using a webclient and also i dont want to use any third party resource. Is there any way to do this. The help will be greatly appreciatted. Thanks in advance

Comment: You probably mean FTPS not SFTP. SFTP is using SSH, while FTPS is TLS added to FTP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FtpWebRequest class and WebClient class(that is use FtpWebRequest for ftp transfers) don't have support of SSH protocol.

Use something like [SSH.NET](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SSH.NET/) package.